# How do I transition between forms C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, user-interface, panel

This may seem like a rather obvious and extremely newcomer question (and it is), but I've merely been attempting to transition between multiple forms in C# Winforms and somehow managed to encounter numerous complications:

1. To begin, I used the obvious:

> ```
> frm_hub hub = new frm_hub();
> hub.Show();
> ```

However, each time this code run, a new instance of frm_hub was created and using hub.Close(); would not work because it was not closing the same new instance of frm_hub

- Is a way to close the same instance of a form from a different form - say with a global variable? Or is there some way to integrate a Close(); so the entire program continues to function and new form displays?

2. As a possible solution to the above issue, I tried to store the same form as a variable:

> ```
> frm_hub hub = new frm_hub();
> private void OpenForm()
> {
>     hub.Show()
> }
> ```

However the runtime error: 'System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.' was showing when I attempted to use this same tactic of storing the form as a variable in the two forms.

- Why is this error occurring? And is there any way I can overcome it?

3. Finally, during some reading to counter this issue I discovered the use of controls and panels, and in this way, I could create an interface that opens different the different forms in a panel

However, my attempt of this required the use of anchors to get the form to display remotely true to the Designer appearance

- If I do not require the form to be resizable, how can use panels to display a different form and at that in a way that displays the design elements how I have them positioned

Apologies again for my beginner understanding and use of terminology, feel free to seek clarification for crucial details I probably haven't included haha,
Thank you!

Comment: The StackOverflowException suggests that you're most likely creating an instance of `frm_hub` inside `frm_hub` (hopefully, you can see the problem with that). Anyway, if you want to access the form in multiple files, then you should create a `public static` variable/property in just one place and use only that. Alternatively, you could use `Application.OpenForms.OfType<frm_hub>().FirstOrDefault()` to get the current open instance of the form.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked a miracle with the public static haha. As a matter of interest (for aesthetics), do you happen to know a method to remove the harsh transition between a .Show() and Close(). I tried a Thread.Sleep(50) before the Close() of the second form but there still appears to be a flash. Using a .ShowDialog() makes a smoother transition, however using the public static form and a .Close() doesn't appear to work as the .Close() exits the form before the .ShowDialog() can be run. No worries if not, thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following, not sure it's best practice. I used a button `ShowFrmHubButton` and disabled it when the window is already shown.

In my example the second form is modal, and you can't use the first window as long as the second is displayed.

```cs
ShowFrmHubButton.IsEnabled = false;
var frmHubWindow = new frm_hub ()
{
    Owner = this
};

frmHubWindow.ShowDialog();
ShowFrmHubButton.IsEnabled = true;
```

Then, when you close\cancel the second form use `this.Close();`

Comment: Hi there! Thank you so much for this solution! Unfortunately the larger issue is that when I navigate to frm_hub say I'm in another form, I was hoping the form I am currently in would close then display frm_hub.ShowDialog() - but this order is not working because it either closes the form before displaying the other form, or it isn't closing the original form at all because of the dialog box nature (meaning code is not executed until after dialogue closed). Do you happen to know how to solve? Thanks!

Comment: I might: since you declared an owner, you can use ```var parent = Owner as MainWindow;``` and then ```parent.Hide();```
note that you can't use ```parent.Close()``` as it owns the frmHubWindow, and I think you can't use it in the constructor.

Comment: (Seriously again I cannot thank you enough for your help) Hmmm yes definitely though the issue is then re-showing with say parent.ShowDialog() as a new dialog opens each time so I end up with like 10 instances if the user chooses to keep opening it, but showdialog won't re-open unless .Close() is used oh man my mind haha

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to show more than one frm_hub?
Do both windows need to be shown at once?

Comment: Hm no i'd prefer not, like basically when the hub navigation button is clicked I would like the hub form to show but so it is a smoother transition (just using frm_hub.Show() makes a strange flicker), I'd like to close the current form the user is in (so that there is not multiple instances of it open). However, using .Hide() for some reason causes multiple instances of the form to keep opening (as the var frmHubWindow = new frm_hub () is called each time the button event occurs so its creating a new frmHubWindow each time

Comment: Like to visualise in code it is currently  just: frm_hub frmHubWindow = new frm_hub(); frmHubWindow.ShowDialog(); this.Close();  but this is creating a new frmHubWindow instance each time

Comment: Hmmm i've been mulling on this issue more more and I think the larger complication with the above issue is the order of the Close() and ShowDialog() and if there is a way to re-use ShowDialog() without using a close

Comment: I think there are 2 separate problems here: displaying a form from another form, and doing it only once.
Couldn't you write a public function in the Owner window that returns if it already created a child?